# java multiple user voice chat over a tcp connection using sockets

Tags: java, tcp, voip

i can't be able to stream mic voice to different clients.

I have Created a java application which can use tcp connection for chat and voice stream within a local network, in this the chat functionality is working fine within every client but the voice streaming is an issue. only two clients were able use the voice feature, not all of them. The basic idea is whoever starts the MD class will able to record the voice and stream it to different clients, and all the connected clients will only listen to the voice(not reply).

i am a beginner in java programming, so i can't figure out the issue. if anyone can please me in this. Thank you in advance.

//MD.java

```
public class MD 
{
ServerSocket MyService;
Socket clientSocket = null;
InputStream input;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
OutputStream out;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
int Size = 10000;
byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[Size];
static Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

MD() throws LineUnavailableException, HeadlessException, UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
   /*JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Network Phone");
   JLabel label = new JLabel("Server ip: "+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), JLabel.CENTER );
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   */

  // frame.pack();
  // frame.show();
   try {
       Mixer mixer_ = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[1]);   // Select Available Hardware Devices for the speaker, for my Notebook it is number 1
       audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
       DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
       sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
       sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
       sourceDataLine.start();
       MyService = new ServerSocket(5000);
       clientSocket = MyService.accept();
       captureAudio();
       input = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
       out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      Thread readbffr = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           try{
               while (input.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
           sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, Size);
       }
               }
           catch(IOException ex){
               //Handle This Too
               ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       };
   });

   readbffr.start();



   } catch (IOException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
   }

}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
   float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
   int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
   int channels = 2;
   boolean signed = true;
   boolean bigEndian = false;
   return new AudioFormat(
           sampleRate,
           sampleSizeInBits,
           channels,
           signed,
           bigEndian);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws LineUnavailableException, UnknownHostException, HeadlessException, InterruptedException {
   MD s2 = new MD();



}

private void captureAudio() {
   try {

       audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
       DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
               TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
       Mixer mixer = null;
       System.out.println("Server Ip Address "+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
       System.out.println("Available Hardware Devices:");
       for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
           mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);      // Select Available Hardware Devices for the micro, for my Notebook it is number 3
           if (mixer.isLineSupported(dataLineInfo)) {
               System.out.println(cnt+":"+mixerInfo[cnt].getName());
               targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
           }
       }
       targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
       targetDataLine.start();

       Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
       captureThread.start();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);

   }
}



class CaptureThread extends Thread {

   byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[Size];

   @Override
   public void run() {
       try {
           while (true) {
               int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
               out.write(tempBuffer);
               out.flush();

           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e);

       }
   }
}}
```

//Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

    boolean stopCapture = false;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee i = new Employee();
                i.captureAudio();

    }
    void captureAudio() {
        try {
                String IP =InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            sock = new Socket("192.168.1.1",5000);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            System.out.println("Available Hardware devices:");
            for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
                System.out.println(cnt+":"+mixerInfo[cnt].getName());
            }
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
/*
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);    //Select Available Hardware Devices for the micro, for my Notebook it is number 3.

            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();

            Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
            captureThread.start();
*/
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo1 = new DataLine.Info(
                    SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem
                    .getLine(dataLineInfo1);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();

            Thread playThread = new PlayThread();
            playThread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    class CaptureThread extends Thread {

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stopCapture = false;
            try {
                while (!stopCapture) {

                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                            tempBuffer.length);

                    out.write(tempBuffer);

                    if (cnt > 0) {

                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);

                    }
                }
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;

        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;

        int channels = 2;

        boolean signed = true;

        boolean bigEndian = false;

        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
                bigEndian);
    }

    class PlayThread extends Thread {

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (in.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
                    sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, 10000);

                }
                sourceDataLine.drain();
                sourceDataLine.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Completely independently of your direct problem, TCP is not good for voice because your voice packets are delay-sensitive: If they don't arrive on time, they're useless. TCP, however, will hold up the rest of the data trying to redeliver anyway.

Comment: I am thinking of using a UDP for connection. But here main issue is distributing the audio to different client, i know that TCP can manage multiple clients for chat purpose, but I won't be able to do that in audio. If you can recommend a solution considering the code, please.